# "Downloads" custom post type used for displaying app download links

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok here's the deal I'm creating a custom WP theme for an mobile app. I want to display 2 download links for iOS and Android in a section on home page.

I created a custom post type called downloads and associated custom meta boxes to that custom post type.

I created 2 posts, one is with a ios download link and the other one is a play store link.

Now I have a problem when I query this post type on front page, both meta boxes display the output although only 1 has the link, see screenshoot:

[image: issues]

This is my code at the moment:

```
<?php
                            $downloads = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'downloads','posts_per_page'=>2, 'order'=>'ASC'));
                            if ($downloads) { ?>

                                <?php foreach ($downloads as $post) { setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                                            <a href="<?php echo(types_render_field("download-play-store", array('raw' => true) )) ; ?>" target="_blank">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array( 'class' => '')); ?> <!-- featured img -->
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="<?php echo(types_render_field("download-app-store", array('raw' => true) )) ; ?>" target="_blank">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array( 'class' => '')); ?> <!-- featured img -->
                                            </a>
                                            </div>
                                <?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>         
                                <?php } ?>
```

How to set some "if" condition which will help not to display the other field if there is no link added to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: i dont have much experience using the types plugin. But this should run without any issues.

```
<?php
$downloads = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'downloads','posts_per_page'=>2, 'order'=>'ASC'));
if ($downloads) {
   foreach ($downloads as $post) { 
       setup_postdata( $post );
        if(types_render_field("download-play-store", array('raw' => true) ))){  ?>
        <a href="<?php echo(types_render_field("download-play-store", array('raw' => true) )) ; ?>" target="_blank">
                                                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array( 'class' => '')); ?> <!-- featured img -->
                                                </a>
<?php }
if(types_render_field("download-app-store", array('raw' => true) )){?>
<a href="<?php echo(types_render_field("download-app-store", array('raw' => true) )) ; ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array( 'class' => '')); ?>
</a>
<?php }?>
</div>
<?php } wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

Comment: Omer, thanks for your time, could I ask you to include the whole code as I'm just a PHP beginner and I didn't succeed to add your "if condition" by myself as you suggested? Thanks

Comment: omer, I really appreciate your time, but sadly this doesn't still work and it look like some small error is in question :( I'm getting this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'"

This row has the error: 
if(types_render_field("download-play-store", array('raw' => true) ))){  ?>

Any idea? Thank you so much!

Comment: EDIT: I just removed one bracket that was an issue, and now all is fine! Thanks so much omer :)